# Typescript type can not be inferred if function parameter is used

Tags: typescript

Lets say i have this generic function:

```js
const myFn = <T>(p: {
  a: (n: number) => T,
  b: (o: T) => void,
}) => {
  // ...
}
```

If i use `myFn` with no parameter for function `a` it works and the type of `T` can be inferred from the return type of `a`:

```js
myFn({
  a: () => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter of a is ignored
  b: o => { o.n }, // Works!
})
```

but if i want to use the parameter for function `a` suddenly the type of T can not be inferred:

```js
myFn({
  a: i => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter i is used
  b: o => { o.n }, // Error at o: Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
})
```

Can someone explain this behavior? How can i fix this such that the type of T can be inferred from the return type of a?

Comment: This looks like an issue of Typscript which is unable to infer the T correct type (inferring as `unknown` in case of having parameter). I think you can work around this issue until it gets fixed by using high order function technique `myFn = (a: (...arg: any[]) => T) => (b: (o: T) => void) {}`. It should work then.

Comment: Strange, it also works if you specify `i`'s type explicitly https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGJhgXhgHgCoD4AUADgFwwDeAUDDAIan5ilgCucARgKYBOAlOrjGwAaKjDb0QpbHzQCAbiACWAExEBfGQMrUA9DpgA6IxTUUKiFPm216mmFZiMYABhgahMPTAAKNLjTgOKG4YEAAzWhhFCCiAczAQLg5lUXFQ-nJQg1Q1Dy8AdUSAawgAQhMeMwswK1E6e0UmVk5eDIcnV3dPfV9-QOCuKKiY5ghk1NIQDLIsnPUeIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AFTER TypeScript 4.7**

Just switch to TypeScript 4.7, see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods)

**BEFORE TS 4.7**

Extra generic for `b` should help:

```js
const myFn = <T,>(p: {
  a: (n: number) => T,
  b: <U extends T /* EXTRA U generic */>(o: U) => void,
}) => {
  // ...
}


myFn({
  a: () => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter of a is ignored
  b: o => { o.n }, // Works!
})

myFn({
  a: i => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter i is used
  b: o => { o.n }, // Works 
})
```

This [article](https://codewithstyle.info/Strict-function-types-in-TypeScript-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance/) should help to understand why your approach did not work

Comment: My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550146/how-typescript-infers-callbacks-arguments-type