# How TypeScript infers callbacks arguments type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My question is based on this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540887/typescript-type-can-not-be-inferred-if-function-parameter-is-used)

Let's say we have next code:

```js
const myFn = <T,>(p: {
  a: (n: number) => T,
  b: (o: T) => void,
}) => {
  // ...
}


myFn({
  a: () => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter of a is ignored
  b: o => { o.n }, // Works!
})


myFn({
  a: i => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter i is used
  b: o => { o.n }, // Error at o: Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
})
```

I was able to fix it. It works with extra generic:

```js
const myFn = <T,>(p: {
  a: (n: number) => T,
  b: <U extends T /* EXTRA U generic */>(o: U) => void,
}) => {
  // ...
}
```

I have fixed it intuitively. I can't explain why this error occured, and even more why my solution helped :)

I believe the answer is in Covariant/Contrvariant/Invariant/Bivariant definitions.

Could you please explain me why this error occured and why my solution works?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

It seems that this behavior is fixed/updated in [TypeScript 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods)

Comment: you can add param type explicitly without extra generics, `a: (i: number) => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter i is used`

Comment: @ABOS Good point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Used terms

[Contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing): The type, a code position must have based on the surrounding type it is assigned to.

[Context-sensitive function](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25092#issuecomment-420068200): function expression with untyped parameters. The parameter type is derived from the contextual type.

#### Example

```
type Fn = (s: string) => number
const fn : Fn = s => s.length 
// `s => s.length` is context-sensitive function
// contextual type of `s` is `string`, obtained from `Fn`
```

#### How type inference works

The compiler does type inference in *two phases*:

- first it infers all non-context-sensitive functions.
- In the second phase inference results for type parameters (like `T`) are then used to infer context-sensitive functions.

If there are no inference candidates from phase 1 to be used in 2, you will probably get a type problem - in question case that is `T` getting type `unknown`.

#### Carried over to your cases

Case 1:

```
myFn({
  a: () => ({ n: 0 }), 
  b: o => { o.n }
})
```

`b` is context-sensitive, `a` not (parameter-less function). So, in the first phase we can analyze `a` and infer `T` to be `{ n: number }`, which then can be used to type parameter `o` in `b` for phase 2. All fine here.

Case 2:

```
myFn({
  a: i => ({ n: 0 }), // Parameter i is used
  b: o => { o.n }, // Error at o: Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
})
```

Here is the devil. Both `a` and `b` are context-sensitive, so we need to skip phase 1 - no inference candidates for `T`. Both functions are now analyzed *independently* from each other in phase 2. This is a problem for the parameter type in `b`, as we cannot consult `a` anymore, what inferred type `T` has.

The only way is to infer `unknown` from the base constraint - and worse: the contextual type of `T` gets "fixed", as the internal TypeScript algorithm for phase 2  needs to have a concrete type instantiation at this point for `T` due to certain restrictions/optimizations. So we are irreversibly stuck with `unknown` for `T`.

Case 3:

```
const myFn = <T,>(p: {
  a: (n: number) => T,
  b: <U extends T /* EXTRA U generic */>(o: U) => void,
}) => {
  // ...
}
```

works, as you introduced a complete new type parameter `U` with new inferences being made, independent from `T`. This is a clever workaround, though I haven't tested, if there are any downsides with this approach.

#### Alternative solution

In order to solve nasty edge cases with type inferences, just make sure that at least one function with type parameters is *not* context-sensitive, by typing the function parameter explicitly.

For example, it is sufficient to type `n: number` inside `a`:

```
myFn({
  a: (n: number) => ({ n: 0 }),  // n explicitly typed
  b: o => { o.n }, // works again
})
```

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGJhgXhgHgCoBoB8AFAA4BcMA3gFAwwCG5hY5YArnAEYCmATgJTp8MPDRgdGIctgFohANxABLACa4qAXxlCKMAPQAqGADoTMfbpjqqVRCkLVaDGIS3OdzGAAZLfXHosABtgBMMB0qNwwimAAZrw8XMowMTwgcDBg4AC0oGBQXAAesBBckIpQinJcyaxgwBXgMAF0IVAgYtUBFB5snLzqISQAFnQlMACMfKLiMO2ylLNGqOp+uhbRMMQjYwBMftFxCXXVYWDKKnT5Td0s7Nw8A8kgPE3BURAwrCVJbTBQCMROiAAhopjZkGB7KInKh5vYMuRvJo1LQZnNtItlij-GIQFAhrQYrV6opwB86AlQuB8kUsiUyhUqn4hqVgNVMlFYrxWdUYs9XiENltRtVxkYYAAFbbVHahcKZWBfarhBBys4XfLks6iNac6DhCqXLgfIIhUZNWoAa0yAHcwCDNNZbJCHPRGD07rxXPCPEjfLRdahCsQADaKYDlEOq-6A5TTcjohYgJaWVYWG3PS3kgDmdGioOsuoAiqxjQ1UHQQ-keGBLpVqjbygS6MpzuXK38AdViBS6HAuNXrLloPAIbKMDgCCRyK6nExbn1+IJhNiZpgAKowQr5M4fbBESQwdeuBQqNSaZeu4ewWAYYhGOiEAAsOymtHvHFEH8IUCmVnBKA7PCMLLj6iI+H4aKXpilg+EAA)

Comment: Note: this is to the best of my knowledge. Information is spread sparingly among github issues and blogs, so please free to comment/criticize if you don't agree with any of the points.

Comment: Thank You very much. It is very good answer. You have a really deep knowledge of TS compiler!