# Enforce function signature within an object

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to define an object with two functions where one function always gets the return type of the other function as a parameter. E.g.

```
type DoActionArgType = { contactId: string };

type Args<T> = 
{
  doAction: (arg: DoActionArgType) => string; // <-- returns string
  onEnd?: (arg: string) => void; // <-- takes string as the argument
}
```

Now I want this to work for arbitrary return types and promises, which works fine, except if I do not add the type to the function `doAction` function argument.

```
export type $Unwrap<T> = T extends Promise<infer U>
    ? U
    : T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer U>
    ? U
    : T extends (...args: any) => infer U
    ? U
    : T;

type DoActionArgType = { contactId: string };

type Args<T> = 
{
  doAction: (arg: DoActionArgType) => Promise<T>;
  onEnd?: (arg: $Unwrap<T>) => void;
}

function test<T>(arg: Args<T>) {}

const doAction = async ({ contactId }) => 1

test({
  // doAction: async ({ contactId }: DoActionArgType) => 1, // Works
  // doAction: async () => 1, // Works
  // doAction, // Works
  doAction: async ({ contactId }) => 1, // <--- Does not work
  onEnd: (arg) => {
    const a:number = arg
  }
})
```

I assume that typescript does not understand that the function signature matches ? Because `contactId` is actually typed `string` just `arg` of onEnd is typed as `unknown`. Is there any way to make this work without adding the `DoActionArgType` type to the `doAction` function ?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1&q=417#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-IQKFwLAQeA4VXeG7MB4WanM9QYrH4DRYYHcABGiWoG28qO9QA)

Comment: What do you need the `$Unwrap` type for, why not just use `onEnd?: (arg: T) => void`

Comment: @MrCodingB `(arg: T) => void` will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a hat trick:

```js
type DoActionArgType = { contactId: string };

type PromiseUnwrap<P> =
  P extends Promise<infer Value>
  ? Value
  : P

const test = <T,>(arg: {
  doAction: (a_arg: DoActionArgType) => T;
  onEnd: <U extends T>(b_arg: PromiseUnwrap<U>) => void;
}) => {
  // ...
};

test({
  doAction: async ({ contactId }) => 1,
  onEnd: (arg) => {
    arg // number
    arg.toExponential // ok
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gQQMbAJZwHYIE4HMAq40AvFAN5RKbACGKAkgCYBcUAzsNqhrlAL4BuAFAjQkKAAVscALao2EAKoYA7thpgAPBIB8UYkKiSoEAB7AIGRm0nS5CzdwBmEbFABqNADYBXCDsMoAH4Pbz9A1gwIADdXEREqDA4oC2TSTXwAGh0ACho8VjJAxkQUdAxWPIB9fNxWeGQ0TBwCIgBKfT18YSNMAFErVk1FE3NLayh8XIAjGoLbWXklVXUtRR0O4j1ouFRGYT5NvSKjAHpTqAA6a6FBUQgOHKLi0qaKqBo2EAwkKCfKah0YBMfhHKAARkygX6gz%20tTBJyMHzwUHOUAwPhk0ziSORuEuwDgfVMYEwljQ3lRFzgAGtAnxbm0gA)

`PromiseUnwrap` - obtains Promise return type.

You might ask, why this function does not work:

```js
const test = <T,>(
  arg: {
    doAction: (a_arg: number) => T;
    onEnd: (b_arg: T) => void
  }) => {
  // ...
};
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550146/how-typescript-infers-callbacks-arguments-type) you can find a good answer.

If you want to learn more about callbacks in typescript, you can read my  [article](https://catchts.com/callbacks). First example will be yours

Comment: I think you should keep the OPs original $Unwrap type in this case, because now you assume that T has to be a Promise, but it's not specified

Comment: Feel free to use your version of $Unwrap. In this case it works in a same way

Comment: @MrCodingB changed

Comment: Why do you use `<T,>` instead of `<T>` ?  Does this make any difference ?

Comment: @Philiiiiiipp is is all about JSX parsing. For instance, it works without comma in IDE but when you want to use `<T>` in playground - it gives an error because TS expects `jsx`. Because I'm always using TS playground I have to put a comma everywhere