# TypeScript: factory with custom methods - 2nd step

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a factory and I need to eventually add custom methods.

Thanks to the community I got a bit closer to the desired solution with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70334385/4690946), but **I need to add a useless argument** to make it working as expected.

Here is a reworked code from the previously said answer.

```js
type Base = { id: string }
type Factory<E> = new () => E;

function factory<E extends Base>(name: string): Factory<E>;
function factory<E extends Base, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, methods: M, useless?: (this: E & M) => void
): Factory<E & M>;
function factory<E extends Base, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, methods?: M, useless?: (this: E & M) => void
): Factory<E> {
  const ret = function(this: Base) {
    this.id = "0"
  };

  Object.defineProperty(ret, "name", { value: name });
  if(methods) Object.assign(ret.prototype, methods);

  return ret as unknown as Factory<E>;
}

const T2 = factory(
  "T2",
  {
    test: function(repeat = true) {
      if(repeat) this.test(false);
      return "test";
    }
  },
  function() {} // If we comment out this line, the TypeScript magic breaks (but not the JavaScript one)
);
const t2 = new T2();
console.log(t2, t2.id, t2.test());
```

**If we comment out the** `useless` **argument, the** `test` **method is no longer visible inside its definition!**

Any idea on how to make this works even without the `useless` argument?

Here is a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBeqxw) to experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`methods` is a record where each key is a `string` and value is a function. It means that you need to overload each function of `methods` record.
Consider this example:

```js
type Base = { id: string }
type Factory<E> = new () => E;

function factory<E extends Base>(name: string): Factory<E>;
function factory<E extends Base, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, methods: M & Record<string, (this: E & M) => void>
): Factory<E & M>;
function factory<E extends Base, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, methods?: M
): Factory<E> {
  const ret = function (this: Base) {
    this.id = "0"
  };

  Object.defineProperty(ret, "name", { value: name });

  if (methods) for (const method in methods) Object.defineProperty(ret.prototype, method, { value: methods[method] });

  return ret as unknown as Factory<E>;
}

const T1 = factory("T1");
const t1 = new T1();
console.log(t1, t1.id);

const T2 = factory(
  "T2",
  {
    test: function (repeat = true) {
      this.foo()
      if (repeat) this.test(false);
      return "test";
    },
    foo: function (repeat = true) {
      this.test()
      return "foo";
    }
  },
);
const t2 = new T2();
console.log(t2, t2.id, t2.test());
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAvbZW)

Please keep in mind that function intersection produces function overloading. This is exactly what I did here `M & Record<string, (this: E & M) => void>`. I have merged `M` with a record where each key is a `string` and value is a function which previous was `useless`

P.S. I have added `foo` just for testing, don't use it in your code without condition statement

Comment: OMG! You so pro! As usual I'll try it during my spear time! Thank you very much once again!

Comment: @DanieleRicci thank you. Sure feel free to ask any questions

Comment: And to let you demonstrate your strength once again... [3rd step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370489/typescript-factory-with-custom-methods-and-variable-id-type) ;) Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi captain! I'm now having troubles with methods with required arguments. If you could check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70453358/typescript-factory-with-custom-methods-3rd-step) please... thank you

Comment: @DanieleRicci sorry, not today :(

Comment: Take your time!

Comment: @DanieleRicci Xmas preparations :D

Comment: Hi captain, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511763/typescript-forconst-a-in-a-b-typeof-a-a-b) is quite easy :)

Comment: You have already got an answer :)

Comment: Yep, it was so fast :) thank you anyway :)