# TypeScript: for(const a of ["a", "b"]) typeof a = "a" | "b"

Tags: typescript

If we write the simple construct, we have:

```js
for(const a of ["a", "b"]) {
    type b = typeof a; // string
}
```

**Is there a way to have?**

```js
for(const a of ["a", "b"]) {
    type b = typeof a; // "a" | "b"
}
```

without repeating all the strings twice?

```js
for(const a of ["a", "b"] as (("a" | "b")[])) {
    type b = typeof a; // "a" | "b"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the array `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `string[]`.

```
for(const a of ["a", "b"] as const) {
    type b = typeof a; // "a" | "b"
}
```

Comment: The in/of was just a typo, thank you for the `as const` !