# TypeScript: factory with custom methods and variable id type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a factory; I need to eventually add custom methods, but thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70334385/4690946) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361134/4690946), we was able to make it work as expected.

Now I need to control the type of the id through an option, once again I'm so close, but I'm still missing something.

I need to control the type of the `id` attribute through the `str` option: if `true` the type of `id` has to be `string`, while if `false` or not provided, the type of `id` has to be `number`, but I get `string | number`.

```js
type Base = { save: () => Promise<boolean> }; // Base and BaseId must be kept separated for next steps ;)
type BaseId<B extends boolean> = { id: B extends true ? string : number };
type Options<B extends boolean> = { opt1?: boolean; opt2?: number; opt3?: string; str?: B };
type Factory<E> = new () => E;

function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>>(name: string, options?: Options<B>): Factory<E>;
function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, options: Options<B>, methods: M & Record<string, ((this: E & M) => void)>
): Factory<E & M>;
function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, options?: Options<B>, methods?: M & Record<string, ((this: E & M) => void)>
): Factory<E> {
  const ret = function (this: E) {};

  Object.defineProperty(ret, "name", { value: name });
  if(methods) Object.assign(ret.prototype, methods);

  return ret as unknown as Factory<E>;
}

const T1 = factory("T1");
const t1 = new T1();
t1.id = "0"; // Error: string | number but number is expected
console.log(t1, t1.id);

const T2 = factory(
  "T2", { str: true }, {
    test: function (repeat = true) {
      if (repeat) this.test(false);
      return "test";
    }
  }
);
const t2 = new T2();
t2.id = "0"; // Ok: string
console.log(t2, t2.id, t2.test());
```

Here is a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvYlkm) to experiment.

Comment: It is not clear for me what you want to achieve. I don't see any TS compiler errors in your code. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Hi @captain-yossarian , thank you again. I described better the problem in the beginning of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `string|number` in your first case because second argument `options` is not provided. You need to change your upper/last overload signature and get rid of `options`.
You need to provide overloaded signature without `options` because `options` is optional parameter. You have provided signature with optional `options`, with required `options` but you did not have signature without `options`. Since `B` generic parameter is binded with `options` argument you need to use some default value instead of `B`.

Consider this example:

```js
type Base = { save: () => Promise<boolean> }; // Base and BaseId must be kept separated for next steps ;)
type BaseId<B extends boolean> = { id: B extends true ? string : number };
type Options<B extends boolean> = { opt1?: boolean; opt2?: number; opt3?: string; str?: B };
type Factory<E> = new () => E;

function factory<E extends Base & BaseId<false>>(name: string): Factory<E>;
function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, options: Options<B>, methods: M & Record<string, ((this: E & M) => void)>
): Factory<E & M>;
function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, options?: Options<B>, methods?: M & Record<string, ((this: E & M) => void)>
): Factory<E> {
  const ret = function (this: E) { };

  Object.defineProperty(ret, "name", { value: name });
  if (methods) Object.assign(ret.prototype, methods);

  return ret as unknown as Factory<E>;
}

const T1 = factory("T1");
const t1 = new T1();
t1.id = "0"; // Error: string | number but number is expected
t1.id = 1; // Ok number
```

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/WzLMQN)
I have used `false` as a default type for `B`

**UPDATE**

`boolean` is a union of `true | false`

If you don't want to touch overload signatures, you can check if `B` is a union. If it is a union (`boolean`) it means that `B` is not infered and we need to use some default value:

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true

type Base = { save: () => Promise<boolean> };
type BaseId<B extends boolean> = { id: IsUnion<B> extends true ? number : B extends true ? string : number }; // <------ CHANGE IS HERE
type Options<B extends boolean> = { opt1?: boolean; opt2?: number; opt3?: string; str?: B };
type Factory<E> = new () => E;

function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>>(name: string, options?: Options<B>): Factory<E>;
function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, options: Options<B>, methods: M & Record<keyof M, ((this: E & M) => void)>
): Factory<E & M>;
function factory<B extends boolean, E extends Base & BaseId<B>, M extends Record<string, <S extends M>(this: E & S) => unknown>>(
  name: string, options?: Options<B>, methods?: M & Record<string, ((this: E & M) => void)>
): Factory<E> {
  const ret = function (this: E) { };

  Object.defineProperty(ret, "name", { value: name });
  if (methods) Object.assign(ret.prototype, methods);

  return ret as unknown as Factory<E>;
}

const T1 = factory("T1",{}, {
  test:function(repeat = true) {
    this.id = 0;
    if(repeat) this.test(false);
  }
});
const t1 = new T1();
t1.id = "0"; // Error: id should be number
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoJVPm)

In general, since `id` is required property and `options` is not, `id` should not rely on `options`.

Made small update. It should be `Record<keyof M, ((this: E & M) => void)>` instead of `Record<string, ((this: E & M) => void)>`

Comment: Yes, the overload is the solution I had already adopted. I was trying to find a solution to avoid another overload... in the real case I have 8 of them and I was trying to reduce some of them. It seems you are confirming I have no other options than the overload :(

Comment: @DanieleRicci made an update

Comment: So strong! It seems there is still a problem: the `id` attribute is not visible in the methods, but I can't understand why since `this` is of type `E & S` and `id` is attribute of `E`: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wR9gxW)

Comment: @DanieleRicci made an update

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Hi cap! I've stopped asking you questions as I'm blocked by another strange problem. This is not related to what we spoken about till now, but if you want to take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414459/wsl2-vscode-doesnt-use-local-tsconfig-json-file) ... thank you

Comment: @DanieleRicci sure, I will take a look