# Typescript generics: infer an object type based on callback return type

Tags: typescript

I have this object transform util function which accepts an object of functions to transform original values immutably.

```js
type ChangeProperties<T extends object, U extends keyof T, S extends Record<U, any>> = {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, U>]: T[P]
} & S;

export const transform = <T extends object, U extends keyof T, S extends Record<U, any>>(
    stat: T,
    transformConf: {
        [P in U]: (val: T[P]) => S[P]
    },
) => {
    return {
        ...stat,
        ...(Object.keys(transformConf) as U[]).reduce((acc, key) => {
            acc[key] = transformConf[key](stat[key]);
            return acc;
        }, {} as Record<U, any>),
    } as unknown as ChangeProperties<T, U, S>;
};

// usage
transform({a: 1, b: "2", c: [1, 2, 3]}, {
    b: val => Number(val),
    c: val => Math.max(...val)
}); // should return { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

However TS cannot infer `S` correctly, which is supposed to be `{ b: number, c: number }`.

How can I solve this problem and does it have anything to do with [contextual type and context-sentitive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553728/12644421)?

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wO2p6W)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mapValuesByObject<O extends Record<keyof M, any>, M extends { [K in keyof O]?: (v: O[K], k: K, o: O) => any }>(
    o: O,
    mapping: M) {
    return {
        ...o,
        ...Object.fromEntries(
            (Object.entries(mapping) as [string, (...args: any) => any][])
                .map(([k, mapper]) => [k, mapper(o[k as keyof O], k, o)])
        )
    } as {
        [P in Exclude<keyof O, keyof M>]: O[P]
    } & {
            [K in keyof M]
            : ReturnType<Extract<M[K], (...args: any) => any>>
        };
}

const x = mapValuesByObject({ a: 1, b: "2", c: [1, 2, 3] }, {
    b: Number,
    c: val => Math.max(...val)
});
x.a // number
x.b // number
x.c // number
```

`O extends Record<keyof M, any>` ensures `M` is a super set of `O`, which means you cannot pass any arbitrary keys for `mapping` argument.

Comment: Very clever technique! Never thought of using concrete mapped type for `M` constraint which helps TS infer properties of M one by one. And also learnt from `Extract<M[K], (...args: any) => any>`!